# User speed increases when joining room

Tags: actionscript-2, smartfoxserver

I am using SmartFoxServer Pro for my game and I have a problem. When a user clicks to one of the doors I have on my main room and changes room, his speed gets increased! Here are my codes:
Click-to-Move code:

```
var myMouse:Object = {}

Key.addListener(keyListener);
myMouse.onMouseDown = function()
{
    if (inited)
    {
        if (!_global.isBusy)
        {
            var px:Number = int(avatarMC._xmouse)
            var py:Number = int(avatarMC._ymouse)



            if ((px > avatarW/2) && (px < areaW - avatarW/2) && (py > avatarH/2) && (py < areaH - avatarH/2))
            {
                // save new variables
                // Please note that init is set to false:
                // this means that we're only moving somewhere and we don't need to init tha avatar
                smartfox.setUserVariables({px:px, py:py, init:false})

                // method derived from the [flashAPI].as
                // moves the mc using the "Quint" equation, with "InOut" easying
                // to the new px,py position in 100 milliseconds.

                myAvatar.easingTo("Quint", "InOut", px, py, 100)

            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Join room code:

```
smartfox.onJoinRoom = function(roomObj:Object)
{
        serverOut.name = _global.myName
    serverOut.sendAndLoad("clothing.php", serverIn, "post")
    serverOutd.name = _global.myName
    serverOutd.sendAndLoad("rank.php", serverInd, "post")
    if (!bListLoaded) {
bListLoaded = true;
_root.smartfox.loadBuddyList();
}
    cleanAvatars()

    var roomId:Number       = roomObj.getId()
    var userList:Object     = roomObj.getUserList()

    resetRoomSelected(roomId)

    _global.currentRoom = roomObj

    // Update Room Name in the avatar area
    currentRoom.htmlText = "Current room: <b>" + roomObj.getName() + "</b>"

    // Clear current list
    userList_lb.removeAll()

    for (var i:String in userList)
    {
        var user:User       = userList[i]
        var uName:String    = user.getName()
        var uId:Number      = user.getId()

        userList_lb.addItem(uName, uId)

        if (uName != _global.myName)
        {
            var uVars:Object = user.getVariables()

            var mc:MovieClip = avatarMC.attachMovie("avatar", "avatar_" + uId,  Number(uId))
            mc._x = uVars.px
            mc._y = uVars.py
            mc.disc.gotoAndStop(uVars.col)
            mc.name.textColor = uVars.rank
            mc.name.text = uName
        }
    }

    // Sort names
    userList_lb.sortItemsBy("label", "ASC")

    setupMyAvatar()
}
```

Change room on collision code:

```
onClipEvent (enterFrame) {
    if (this, hitTest(_root.chatBox.entershop)) {
        _root.chatBox.gotoAndPlay(2);
        //_root.gotoAndStop(17);
        _root.smartfox.joinRoom("The Kitchen");
        //_root.smartfox.setUserVariables({px:"377", py:"175"})
    }
}
```

How can I stop user's speed from getting increased every time he joins a room? Please help!

Comment: umm I didn't find anything related to speed in the above code except for 
`myAvatar.easingTo("Quint", "InOut", px, py, 100)`
try stopping the tween before changing the room, or perhaps change the easing method. that's all I could think of for the above code, I'd perhaps answer better if I can actually test what's actually going on. do you have this setup somewhere online?

Comment: @yawar yes at http://monsterplanet.net/register for register and http://monsterplanet.net/monsterplanet.swf to play. You have to tell me once you register to activate your acc though.

Comment: sorry I was out on a trip , just checked it and registered on the above site. username : yawar